# My SQL DISTINCT and count if

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table:

[image]

I want to write a query to show unique Adid for the specific users:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Adid FROM Message WHERE (MesFrom =1 OR MesTo = 1) AND (MesFrom =2 OR MesTo = 2) ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This works ok

But now I want to add the amount of New messages so i need something like

```
SELECT Count(IF(New=1,1,0)) AS countNew FROM Message
```

But need to combine it with the previous query

The output must be like this:

43 NEW 3
44 NEW 1

Please help!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Adid, SUM(New = 1) new
  FROM Message 
 WHERE (MesFrom = 1 OR MesTo = 1) 
   AND (MesFrom = 2 OR MesTo = 2) 
 GROUP BY Adid
```

Output:

```
| ADID | NEW |
|------|-----|
|   42 |   2 |
|   43 |   3 |
|   44 |   1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d7d8/1)** demo

Comment: That works perfectly!!! THANK YOU! Maybe you can help with another one. I'm new in SQL, have to try 100 variants before I get the desired

SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(Message.MesFrom, Message.MesTo) AS user1
  , GREATEST(Message.MesFrom, Message.MesTo) AS user2
FROM Message WHERE MesFrom = 1 OR MesTo = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC

This outputs the users from the same table, and now I try to add new messages count...

Comment: @AndreyPopov You're welcome. Diluting questions by changing the context or scope is not encouraged here. Therefore please consider to create another question and put all details there along with sample data (in textual form, not picture) and desired output. Other SO members or I will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Adid , Count(IF(New=1,1,0)) AS countNew
FROM Message
WHERE (MesFrom =1 OR MesTo = 1) AND (MesFrom =2 OR MesTo = 2) 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Plese check whether it's working.

Comment: add LIMIT 100 after the sql query

Comment: This one doesn't work( It outputs only one row as DISTINCT checks the unique values of New column as well(

Comment: Thank you Lakmal. Limits are planed in future, for now I just try to make a structure)